# PHP session_start() and dot prefix in domain name dupilicate cookie issue

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I set session with function `session_start()`. This will set PHPSESSID cookie for domain dev.magento2.com. When I go back to page (Magento 2 platform), Magento code adds another php PHPSESSID cookie with leading dot. I read that modern browsers should not care about the leading dot. But in my case it will still create another cookie instead update the existing one.

As you can see in the below image, it will create another PHPSESSID cookie. Why is that?
[image: console]

Comment: because these are different servers. use this to configure session cookie: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: **WAIT** You want one cookie session to magneto app and some your code, where you use `session_start`? It's a bad idea to use the same session for different environments.

Comment: @bato3 it is the same server. The reason why I need session_start is because there is custom php script that is called with ajax and that script uses also session. The reason why this is custom script and not Magento controller is to save spent resources because it is loaded for each page load and must be called with ajax for some other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Because you have different session settings in both cases, but:

**You should not mix data from the magneto and ajax sessions.**

You use something like this `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue('test');`?

Use `print_r($_SESSION)` to check what is in magneto session. The frameworks add some magic to the session...

You have a good chance of causing problems if you push two engines in 1 session. It is also possible to read the session for only one process at a time. The second will be waiting.

Use [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to change session name, and keep different sessions.

If you need to transfer the user to ajax.php, in addition to the data, pass the hash and expiration date.

```
<?php
$valid_time = strtotime('+1 hour');
$user_id = 'x';
$hash = crc32($valid_time.$user_id.'security key');
```

Use all the data, what you pass in the hash generation.